# Finding $v_{rms}$ of a gas molecule using Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, physics

We have the following Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution for speeds of molecules in a gas.

> The number of molecules between speeds $v$ and $v+dv$ are:
>
> $$n(v)dv = 4\pi N \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_{B}T}\right)^{3/2} v^2 e^{-mv^2/2k_{B}T} dv$$
>
> where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann's constant, $T$ is the temperature of the gas, $m$ is mass of a molecule and N is the total number of particles.

Now I am trying to find $v_{rms} = \sqrt{\overline{v^2}}$ and I already know it should come out to be $\sqrt{\frac{3k_{B}T}{m}}$

Here, $\overline{X}$ $\equiv$ average of $X$ over all molecules.

I went about it this way:

$$\overline{v^2} = \frac{1}{N} \int_0^\infty v^2 n(v) dv = \frac{1}{N} \int_0^\infty v^2 4\pi N \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_{B}T}\right)^{3/2} v^2 e^{-mv^2/2k_{B}T} dv$$

$$= 4\pi \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_{B}T}\right)^{3/2} \int_0^\infty v^4 e^{-mv^2/2k_{B}T} dv$$

Now, I looked up this integral:

$$\int _{0}^{\infty } v^{2n} e^{-av^2}\, dv = \frac {(2n-1)!!}{a^n\, 2^{n+1}}{\sqrt {\frac {\pi }{a}}}$$

Putting $n = 2$ and $a = m/2k_{B}T$:

$$\int _{0}^{\infty } v^4 e^{-mv^2/2k_{B}T}\, dv = \frac {3!!}{\left(\frac{m}{2k_{B}T}\right)^2\, 8}{\sqrt {\frac {2\pi k_{B}T}{m}}} = 90\sqrt\pi \left(\frac{2k_{B}T}{m}\right)^{5/2}$$

$$\overline{v^2} = 4\pi \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_{B}T}\right)^{3/2} 90\sqrt\pi \left(\frac{2k_{B}T}{m}\right)^{5/2} = 360 \left(\frac{\pi m}{2\pi k_{B}T}\right)^{3/2} \left(\frac{2k_{B}T}{m}\right)^{5/2} = \left(\frac{720k_{B}T}{m}\right)$$

but this is not the $\left(\frac{3k_{B}T}{m}\right)$ which was correct. Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gaussian integral is not evaluated correctly, though the form you looked up is correct. Note that

$$\int _{0}^{\infty } v^{4} e^{-av^2}\, dv = \frac {3!!}{a^2\, 8}{\sqrt {\frac {\pi }{a}}} = \frac38\sqrt\pi a^{-5/2} \to \frac38\sqrt\pi \left(\frac{2kT}{m}\right)^{5/2} $$

---

As an aside, you can evaluate this integral by hand using:

$$\int _{0}^{\infty } dv\ v^{4} e^{-av^2} = \frac{d^2}{da^2}\int _{0}^{\infty } dv\  e^{-av^2} = \frac{d^2}{da^2}\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{3}{4}a^{-52} $$

Comment: Why is $3!! = 3$? Isnt $3!! = (3!)!$?

Comment: The double factorial notation typically means multiple the evens or the odds down to one, depending on if you start with an even or odd integer. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Comment: So that's where I made a mistake. Thnx a lot.

Comment: What is this technique of $\int_0^\infty v^4 e^{−av^2} = \frac{d^2}{da^2} \int^\infty_0 e^{−av^2}$

Comment: The idea is that since $\int_0^\infty v^4 e^{−av^2} = \int^\infty_0  \frac{d^2}{da^2} e^{−av^2}$, it would be nice to interchange the order of integration and differentiation. This is often no issue with integrals arising in physics. The condition that has to be met is Leibniz's integral rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). Say we wanted to integrate $\int_0^\infty v^4 e^{−v^2}$. We could first solve the above and then limit $a\to1$. It works fine :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sure thing! Glad it was of use. (Note that I forgot the dv in those integrals. That was a typo!)